# Can someone help me Normalize this up to 3NF

Tags: database-normalization, 3nf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7L8Z.png)

Please help me normalize this library system. im confused when doing normalization

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please learn http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think **no need column** for **"Borrowername"** in Borrow table as we link it with student.